# pipe text from external source (such as csv or excel file)

Tags: qualtrics

I want to include 11 columns from external csv file to my survey. On the basis of 11 columns respondent will answer. My question is: can i pipe text from csv file or is there any other way ?

Comment: No, you can't.  If you provide more detail on what you are trying to do, maybe we can suggest another way.

Comment: @T.Gibbons I have some information in external file (such as CSV or txt). I want to piped that information into form, so that participants can give feedback on the basis of that information. Information is same for all participants. However, information changes every week. So next week same survey but with different information will float to the participants. I want to design the form but pipe information from external file so that wont feed information manually every week

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do what you are trying to do with external data is to call a web service script that would return the external information as embedded data fields.

The web service script would read the csv file and format it in json format.  If I were doing it, I would probably import the csv file into a MySQL table and have the script get it from there, but that is just my preference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please direct me some literature that guides me how i can connect MySQL with Qualtrics

Comment: You connect MySQL with Qualtrics through a web script written in php or some other language. So it goes qualtrics->(web service call)->php script->mysql->php script->(json output)->qualtrics.  There are a bunch of resources out there for learning php and MySQL, just do a search.  The key things in php you need are the mysqli class and the json_encode function.